# jQuery datepicker is translucent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to incorporate the jQuery UI datepicker function into a website I'm creating, but for some reason it's showing up translucent. I've read around and aparently it's caused from not linking the css file.

I've linked all of these files in the head in this order:

```
jquery-ui.min.css
jquery-ui.structure.min.css
jquery-ui.theme.min.css
jquery-1.11.3.min.js
jquery-ui.min.js
```

They all came from when I DL'd jQuery UI (except the jQuery v1.11.3 of course)

Then, in the form area I have:

```
<form id="purchase">
    <fieldset class="purchase">
        <input type="text" id="datePicker">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and then in my javascript file I have:

```
$(function() {

    $( '#datePicker' ).datepicker();

});
```

The result is the date picker shows up but it is transparent. I've been staring at this for hours thinking there's something obvious I'm missing but I just can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post a fiddle or a link? You probably have css classes over writting each other

Comment: @kurt - its a large site. It's a fictitious company, [link](http://rocserve.com/test/)

Comment: problem with `main.css` override `jquery ui css`. try to remove `main.css` then check if it works fine then problem in that only.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: kurt is correct some style sheet getting blank.

Comment: what is `<script>if ( !window.jQuery )   {
                document.write( '' );
                document.write( '');
                document.write( '' );
            };` for ?  try to remove that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres something up with your style sheet, not sure what it is but something is inserting an empty style tag into your head, replacing it with jquery-ui.css seems to fix it. Hope fully this works in the source as well.
Change

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
```

To

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
```

Comment: Thats weird. I omitted the second line in your post (as it was supposedly the same thing anyway) and it also works. I wonder what happened. Thank you very much for your help. How did you figure it out?

Comment: @Roclemir I used dev tools, I've come across a lot of weird things like this with javascript as well the first thing I check is that they are included correctly, right order etc. It saves alot of time.

Comment: Problem solved with `live css url` still issue is that why `jquery ui css` included getting blank?. Those are accessible separately but not in this given page.